# User shown opted in but messages failing due to 'not opted in'

Tags: gupshup

I want to send Whatsapp transactional messages to users and for which I am opting in them via Gupshup's WhatsApp API. This is the API that I am using:

[image]

When I go to Opt In users screen, I am able to find users who have opted in via this API. Refer below image for it:

[image]

The issue is when I try to send messages to these users (opt-in via Upload), messages failed citing the reason that user is not opted in. Refer below image for it:

[image]

Users who have opted-in via API seem to have two different status at the same time and I am not able to find out why. Do you know what may be causing this strange issue?

Comment: From your screenshot, it seems your app is in sandbox mode(as source number: +917834811114). The message you are trying to send seems to a preapproved template message or a random message?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sandbox, the you have to send PROXY appname, through your whatsapp.
But once when your app is live, user do not need to send this message, and you will be able to use the workflow you defined above.
Hope it helps!